# How to import clientsmodule from AppModule to other module nestjs

Tags: import, module, microservices, nestjs

I have a registered microservice in app module of Bus.

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'awesomemodule',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 4001,
        },
      },
    ]),
    HealthCheckModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, HealthCheckController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And i want to import this module to other module.

```
@Module({
  providers: [HealthCheckService],
  controllers: [HealthCheckController],
  imports: [],
})
export class HealthCheckModule {}
```

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing the `ClientsModule` directly at the `AppModule` level, you should create a wrapper module that imports and exports the `ClientsModule` with its proper configuration so that you can re-use it. This is called [`module re-exporting`](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting). An example would look like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'awesomemodule',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 4001,
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class AwesomeModule {}
```

Now you can add `AwesomeModule` to the `imports` of any module that has a provider that needs to do `@Inject('awesomemodule')` and it will work without complaining about missing dependencies.